# How to fix the non-updating clock on a tkinter weather app?

Tags: python, tkinter, weather, localtime, system-clock

Clock on tkinter doesn't work

I created a weather app, but the clock just constantly stand still the time, how to fix it???

```
current = datetime.now(home)
real = current.strftime("%d/%m/%Y\n%H:%M:%S %p")
clock.config(text=real)
root.after(1000, clock)


root = Tk()
root.title("Weather App")
root.geometry("910x500") 
root.resizable(0, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's how I do it
I would like the clock to change its minute, I tried but I can't
It just stand still and doesn't change -_-`your text`

Answer (score 1):

.after calls a **function** after a certain time , so the second argument that you give to .after is a function , for example :

```
def update_time():
    current = datetime.now(home)
    real = current.strftime("%d/%m/%Y\n%H:%M:%S %p")
    clock.config(text=real)
    root.after(1000, update_time) #<-- after 1 second the function get called again


root = Tk()
root.title("Weather App")
root.geometry("910x500") 
root.resizable(0, 0)
update_time() #<-- calls the function for the first time so the loop can start

root.mainloop()
```

so you call the function for the first time to start the loop and then the function calls itself after 1 second to update the time